# Babel 7.18 doesn't transpile components outside the project root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have a component `sharedlib` outside the babel root directory of `project1`. I used to use webpack to package this project without problems, but when I configured babel, I got the following error：

```yaml
          Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
    lib1.out.js  63.1 KiB    main  [emitted]        main
lib1.out.js.map  43.2 KiB    main  [emitted] [dev]  main
Entrypoint main = lib1.out.js lib1.out.js.map
[../sharedlib/index.js] 43 bytes {main} [built]
[../sharedlib/util.js] 554 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/lib1.js] 435 bytes {main} [built]
    + 56 hidden modules

ERROR in ../sharedlib/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs3/core-js-stable/promise' in 'D:\test_babel\sharedlib'
 @ ../sharedlib/util.js 3:0-69 13:13-21
 @ ../sharedlib/index.js
 @ ./src/lib1.js

ERROR in ../sharedlib/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/classCallCheck' in 'D:\test_babel\sharedlib'
 @ ../sharedlib/util.js 1:0-76 7:4-19
 @ ../sharedlib/index.js
 @ ./src/lib1.js

ERROR in ../sharedlib/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs3/helpers/createClass' in 'D:\test_babel\sharedlib'
 @ ../sharedlib/util.js 2:0-70 10:2-14
 @ ../sharedlib/index.js
 @ ./src/lib1.js
```

The demo project to reproduce the problem is on github https://github.com/xybei/test_babel

My project directory is like this:

```
ROOT
  ├─project1
  │  │  babel.config.js
  │  │  demo.html
  │  │  demo.js
  │  │  package-lock.json
  │  │  package.json
  │  │  webpack.config.js
  │  │
  │  ├─node_modules
  │  └─src
  │       lib1.js
  │
  └─sharedlib
        index.js
        util.js
        package.json
```

Here's the `project1/package.json`, I have configured `sharedlib` as a local module `"sharedlib": "file:../sharedlib"`

```json
{
  "name": "lib1.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test project1",
  "main": "lib1.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.18.3",
    "sharedlib": "file:../sharedlib"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-loader-exclude-node-modules-except": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.39.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",
    "prerelease": "npm run clean",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "release": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/lib1.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: `lib1.out.js`,
        library: 'Lib1',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // include: [
                //     path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                //     path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/sharedlib')
                // ],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

If I comment out `exclude` and let go of `include`, the compilation will no longer report an error, but the `util.js` in packaged file has not been transpiled, and it is still ES6 code. This is contrary to my expectation. Why is the `node_modules/sharedlib` directory `include`d, but the files in it are not transpiled?

`babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        ["@babel/preset-env",
            {
                targets: {
                    ie: 10
                },
                debug: true
            }]
    ],
    plugins: [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
                corejs: 3
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

`sharedlib` comes from a third party, I don't want to modify and install `@babel/runtime-corejs3` under its directory, can I modify the configuration of my `project1` to transpile the `sharedlib` code? thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@babel/runtime-corejs3` to your `sharedlib` package.json dependency.

```json
{
  "name": "sharedlib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test sharedlib",
  "main": "index.js",
  "module": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.18.3"
  }
}
```

When you use Babel's `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`, you need to add appropriate runtime dependency to the project. For `corejs: 3` option, you would need `@babel/runtime-corejs3`. Look at the required dependencies you need to [additionally install](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime.html#corejs) in order for this to run.

Further, you should use package import instead of relative import:

```js
// Instead of this:
import { Util } from '../../sharedlib';

// Use this:
import { Util } from 'sharedlib';
```

Also, you would need to install this inside `sharedlib` folder's `node_modules` since that's where the `util.js` file is present.

### Without modifying sharedlib

To make this work without modifying `sharedlib` `package.json` file, make Webpack aware of `@babel/runtime-corejs3` using [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). Modify and add following to `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    // Other Webpack configuration
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@babel/runtime-corejs3': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/@babel/runtime-corejs3')
        }
    }
};
```

However, this is not a clean way of doing it. The right approach would be to use a mono-repo setup like npm **workspaces** or similar and have your `node_modules` folders all the way up in the ROOT of the repository. That way, Webpack will not have problem resolving required modules from anywhere in the project structure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have installed `@babel/runtime-corejs3` in the `project1` directory. I don't want to modify the configuration of `sharedlib`. This library is from a third party. If I modify it, it will be troublesome to maintain. Is there a way to modify only the configuration of `project1` to solve this problem?

Comment: @xybei Updated the answer to address your concern.

Comment: Thanks! The method you gave did solve my problem! But I still have a question, I have used npm workspaces, but I used a local `file:` path for `sharedlib` in `package.json`, and generated a `sharedlib` link in `project1\node_modules`, the way of using local path is not supported by babel?

Comment: If you have npm workspaces, you would not need `file:` and you should have a top-level `package.json` at the ROOT of the repository. NPM workspaces then knows how to properly setup `node_modules`.